# Xiaomi Mi A3 - not booting - fastboot erase userdata

Tags: fastboot, xiaomi, mi

I’m a noob.
I follow a guide in the forum **xda-developers** to root my [Xiaomi Mi A3](https://www.mi.com/in/mi-a3/)
I executed the command:

```
fastboot erase userdata
```

After executing the command, I realized that I had deleted the partition.
Now the Device is only booting in to Fastboot.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the link to the guide you were using.

Comment: Sorry, cannot finde the trade anymore. **fastboot erase userdata** is the only command i executed except the command to unlock the bootloader.

Comment: But you wrote `I realized that I had deleted the partition.` so when did you delete it (note erasing just means deleting data not deleting the partition)?

Comment: *fastboot erase* will erase the whole partition, you must recreate file system with *fastboot format:ext4 userdata* (or f2fs)

Comment: use latest standalone [platform-tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) (no need for full sdk)

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

Comment: btw don't use flash_all.bat that will probably re-lock bootloader. download fastboot variant for your ROM version and flash only necessary partitions http://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/archive/miui/laurel

Comment: Hello Teso. Unlike forums, our site allows the post author to edit their post to make changes - whether for removing content or adding one. Therefore, you don't have to make additional posts below. And so, please use "post your answer" button below only when you have an answer to post. :)